# Is it possible for this function to have a negative value?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I have a function $f(x)=(b-1)x+1$ where $b\geq0 $ and $0<x<1$. I want to know is it possible for this function to have a negative value?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not, because $$f(x)=bx+(1-x)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

No, because it is a linear function, thus:
$$f(0)=1>0 \ \ \text{and} \ \  f(1)=b\ge0$$

Answer (score 0):

$b\ge 0$ and $x>0$ so $bx\ge 0$

$0 <x <1$ so $-x +1>0$

So $(b-1)x+1=bx -x +1> bx \ge 0$.